# Trying to persuade a character by persuading the player out of game

Tags: player-communication

I am severely annoyed.

In our group I played a character who is an expert counterfeiter. Our group consists of an investigative agency during the Victorian times and my "normal" mode of operation is securing evidence (high values for chemical analysis, fotography, microscopy and all natural sciences).

The play was very good so far, the other players were aware of my criminal background and tolerated it as long as the group benefitted from my art.
Now we took out together a very powerful group. Those had much money and also a cellar with high-class forgery equipment.

Two of us took out some real money (I had enough; the intention for me was that the powerful group had damaged our client. The in-game boss suspected something, but we were together with a coroner and would talk about it later) and I returned later and stealed one of five printing plates. Knowing that our in-game boss does not like to be outsmarted, I hid the plates very carefully and out of reach, left no traces and also informed the GM only with a hidden message. The GM agreed. Naturally the other players visited the cellar one time again and noticed the missing plate.

In the next round it was evident that both our in-game boss and GM have talked together. Instead of talking to my character, the **player** addressed me as **player** that my character should give the plates back.
The problem was that all the reasons he mentioned are only valid for the **character**.

- He promised the coroner that he would everything in his might to
  secure the evidence. The problem is: He has no influence about my
  decisions as character and if my character denies involvement,
  his **character** did everything in his might to fulfill the promise
  and cannot be hold responsible for my actions if I lie to him. Yes, he
  can fire me on suspicion. Yes, he may come to the conclusion that
  I am untrustworthy because I could tamper the evidence in future.
  Yup, but it is still my decision what my character does.
- He said that he would find out the plates anyway and then I would
  be arrested. I said: "Fine, go on and search ". He realized
  that I prepared for this and that he would not succeed.
- The group are depending on trust of each other. True, but first
  they accepted criminal activity when it suited them. And even a
  crook can be very trustworthy depending on the circumstances. It
  is still a decision to be made.

What really irked me is that I get the impression he had the foregone conclusion ("The plates will be given back") and therefore tried to weasle out of actually **playing** the confrontation. After more than 40 minutes discussion we finally played the confrontation and ironically it came out
that the GM screwed up -- I could not have stolen the plates.

There are extremely many and very exciting possibilities. I could have been convinced by talk. He could have failed and admitted defeat. I could have (as it actually played) ended smoothly because the GM screwed up. All those things which are so good in RPGs.

Instead I feel angry and left with a bitter taste.

**If Player A tries to persuade Player B so that B's character do something to A's wishes, when is it A) unfair and B) how can I convince A that his approach is detrimental to the play when the situation occurs ?**

Comment: system agnostic or name the game.

Comment: I find this question highly confusing. Was it a LARP or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a good in-game way to resolve this problem.

Here's what's going on in-game: the other characters know that someone stole some counterfeiting equipment, and it was very likely one of their group.  The characters also know that your character has the skills to make use of counterfeiting equipment, and they know that your character has a criminal background.  They can ask your character: "did you steal from us?" and it becomes a contest of your ability to lie versus their ability to detect lies.  But you've hidden the loot, so they can't get it back, and they don't have enough evidence to turn you in to the police.

Here's how this would go in real life: your character doesn't get arrested, because nobody has any evidence and you've covered your tracks too well.  But the other characters are pretty sure you did it, and they don't trust you any more; they never do a job with your character again.

This *can't happen in an RPG*.  The players are all sitting around the same table, and the GM is telling a story about your characters as a group.  The GM isn't going to split the group in two.  If the game goes this way, everyone has to uninvite you from the group, and they're too polite to do that.

So they want to convince you out-of-character.

---

I think this is a [Same Page Tool](https://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-same-page-tool/) problem.

It sounds like you want to play a cloak-and-dagger game in which characters pursue their own interests, even if those interests are counter to the goals of the group.  Maybe the characters can come up with their own reasons to keep interacting with each other even when none of them trust each other; maybe the GM just goes around and does solo scenes with each character.

It sounds like this other guy wants to play a fully-cooperative game in which characters are unified in their pursuit of the main story goal.

So essentially you're having an argument about which of those games you're playing.

The worse problem is that the GM seems to want the fully-cooperative game as well: he's running a game in which you're an investigative agency, and investigative agencies do have to trust each other.

Here's what I think you should do: while you're playing this game, be trustworthy.  Make up a reason why your character doesn't want to steal evidence from the group -- or, if that's too hard, remove your character from the group and bring in a different one that isn't a criminal.  Maybe later you can play some other game in which betraying the group is explicitly part of the fiction.  (Paranoia, perhaps?)

---

I'll add a side note: I've played in games in which the thief stole from the group.  She'd say to the DM: "I search for treasure!" and the DM would tell us what she found, and she'd say: "I keep it for myself and don't tell anyone."  When that happens to me, it's deeply frustrating.  It makes me feel like a sucker, like I'm being taken advantage of.  It makes me not want to be in that game any more.

Please don't make your fellow players feel that way.  :)

Comment: Your anecdote at the end reminds me of the one time I pulled that (taking some kind of emergency healing artifact from a pedestal before the others entered the room), but instead of keeping it for myself I did wait for the group to sleep and hid it in the equipment of the fighter.  I somehow knew that he would most likely need it and I did want to evade the trouble of convincing the rest of the group of that. Turned out I was pretty right  - it won us the end boss that the Paladin didn't drop dead after the second onslaught and allow us to make it a win.

Comment: @DanB What I really find impressive that even bad questions can generate very good answers. Nicely done.